# Grails index.gsp considers action as a view and throws error

Tags: grails

My Grails index.gsp (domain class's view) throws an error 500: `"Could not resolve view with name '/someClass/auth' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet' "`

I have defined an empty action `def auth={}` in my controller and there is nothing but a text field and a button with `g:form` action `auth`

/user/index.gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'someClass.label', default: 'SomeClass')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <g:form action="auth">
        <a href="#list-someClass" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
                <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
                <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <input type="submit" value="login"/>

        </g:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the gsp is in `/user/index.gsp`, by convention, grails expect `UserController` and a method called `auth`. If the `auth` method is in different controller, make sure you add the name in the controller attribute of `g:form`

```
<g:form controller="<controller-name>" action="auth">
```

Comment: Hello Sir,It is just a simple app with just one domain and a controller class

Comment: Domain by itself can not handle form action. A domain only represents a table in your data model. I advise to read through grails documentation.

Comment: My domain class is SomeClass.groovy, i have a Controller SomeClassController which has an action def auth={, Isn't that enough for form to call the action from the gsp?

Comment: Let say your domain is `User` and your controller is `UserController`, then controller specific gsp(s) should be `grails-app/view/user` folder. When you have a method called `auth` in `UserController`, which hasn't defined any view to render, then grails expect that you have a `aut.gsp` in `user` folder. Do you have that?

Comment: Thank you so much sir, That solved it, my method wasn't redirecting to any view.